# Why would kern.log stop logging after crash & reboot

Tags: logging, kernel, rsyslog

Server: Ubuntu 12.04

I recently noticed that my servers kern.log had stopped logging. I've not separated iptables from the kern.log so it used to be very active, however recently it's been logging nothing at all. Syslog however is still working fine.

By default the virtual server is setup to use rsyslog as the logging daemon.

Running: `sudo dmesg -c` shows there is still output to be logged & the dmesg logs still logs each server reboot.

What could cause kern.log to stop being written too?

The only other record of this problem, I could find was [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysklogd/+bug/255635) Ubuntu bug report, which was solved back in 2008.

**More information - after comments**

The hard drive has about 21GB free and there are no messages in dmesg about corruption.

I also tried re-naming the current kern.log to force it generate a new one, but nothing has happened.

**Extra Information - Random shutdowns**

It's also worth mentioning (although probably not useful, because as of this moment I haven't managed to diagnose the problem), the server currently is having some issues with random shutdowns and the random shutdowns appear to trigger the kern.log logging.

i.e. After one random shutdown, on reboot it stops logging and then when it randomly shutdowns again, on reboot it starts logging.

Comment: You should check if the disk is full. You should also check if there is any file system corruption preventing writes to the file. If there is any file system corruption, you can most likely find messages about that in the kernel log. (And you can see the most recent kernel log messages using the `dmesg` command, regardless of whether they have been written to a file or not.)

Comment: @kasperd Thanks for the advice! No luck this time around though, plenty of space on the disk and nothing about corruption in dmesg, in fact the only none iptables message is "[18698.060036] hrtimer: interrupt took 31271808 ns".